# Workbench Moderation - Issues with New Drafts of Published Nodes

Tags: workbench

I'm using [Workbench](https://drupal.org/project/workbench) for workflow, along with [Workbench Access](https://drupal.org/project/workbench_access), [Workbench Moderation](https://drupal.org/project/workbench_moderation) and [Workbench Moderation Notes](https://drupal.org/project/workbench_moderation_notes) on a new Drupal 7 site.

I have set up rules for emailing approvers/editors on certain moderation state changes which work for the most part.

However, when I create a new draft of a published node, the Draft to Needs Review emails are not triggered unless I explicitly save the node first. This will be quite a common occurrence when the site goes live and I would much prefer the users not having to save the node before changing the status.

Does anyone know why this is happening or any workaround (e.g. use `node_save()` somewhere to save in the background)?

Comment: What event are you using in your Rule to trigger the email?  What version of Workbench Moderation are you using (it may matter here)?

Comment: I'm using Workbench Moderation 7.x-1.3 and the "After moderation transition" event. This works except in the case outlined above. Thanks.